# Component VirtualList, scroll programatically to the end of the list

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Included in the page is a VirtualList like in the sample page

```
VirtualList<Person> list = new VirtualList<>();
list.setItems(people);
list.setRenderer(personCardRenderer);
add(list);
```

The list itself contains many items and items will be periodically added to the end of the list. I initially want to show the last items of list.

I'm unable to find an API to scroll either to a specific index nor to the end of the list. Neither trying to scroll via Javascript was successfull.
Does exists a solution for this problem or is the (very fast) VirtualList the right component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the element [documentation](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/23.3.1/#/elements/vaadin-virtual-list), there is a method, `scrollToIndex`. Looking at the Java API [documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.3.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/virtuallist/VirtualList.html), there is no Java API to call this method.

You can still call it like so:

```java
list.getElement().callJsFunction("scrollToIndex", INDEX);
```

If you plan on doing this often, make a utility method, or, better yet, extend `VirtualList` and use your class instead, e.g.:

```java
public class MyVirtualList<T> extends VirtualList<T> {
  ...constructors

  // Could just return `void`.
  public PendingJavaScriptResult scrollToIndex(int index) {
    return getElement().callJsFunction("scrollToIndex", index);
  }
}
```

I reported the missing Java API for `scrollToIndex` and a PR was opened: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/pull/4451.